# How to install Cinnamon with SLiM on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, cinnamon

I have recently installed Arch Linux and since I'm new to hard it's a little hard to get around the things in here.

I wanted to know how I can instal cinnamon desktop environment with SliM display manager.

By now, I know how to install Arch system and boot into the root account. I have also installed the system X and currently I'm able see the basic GUI using:

```
 startx
```

I installed cinnamon and slim using:

```
 # pacman -S cinnamon
 # pacman -S slim
```

The problem, now, is that I don't know how to configure both the programs to start at boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the ArchLinux wiki on SLiM, especially this sections: [Enabling SLiM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SLiM#Enabling_SLiM) and [multiple environments](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SLiM#Multiple_environments).

Comment: It took me some time and I had to finally install the system again. Although I am able to log in properly using root account, but still non root users can not login. Don't know why.